# Write a Stream<String> to a file Java

Tags: java, collections, java-8, stream, java-stream

I'm reading a file using the java NIO package's `Files.lines()` method, which gives an output of type `Stream<String>`. After some manipulation to the String records I want to write it to a file.
I've tried collecting it to a list using `Collectors.toList()`, and it works for smaller data set. The problem occurs when my file has almost 1 million lines(records), the list isn't able to hold as many records.

```
// Read the file using Files.lines and collect it into a List
        List<String> stringList = Files.lines(Paths.get("<inputFilePath>"))
                                    .map(line -> line.trim().replaceAll("aa","bb"))
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());


//  Writes the list into the output file
        Files.write(Paths.get("<outputFilePath>"), stringList);
```

I'm looking for a way I can read a large file, manipulate it (as done in the `.map()` method in my example), and write it into a file without storing it into a List(or collection).

Comment: you can use stream.forEach(line -> file.write(line)) to do this

Comment: I think you should open a FileWriter before, so instead of `collect(Collections.toList)` you can do something like `.forEach(line -> output.write(line)`

Comment: `Files.write(Paths.get("<outputFilePath>"), () -> { try { return Files.lines(Paths.get("<inputFilePath>")) .<CharSequence>map(line -> line.trim().replaceAll("aa","bb")).iterator(); } catch(IOException ex) { throw new UncheckedIOException(ex); } });`

Comment: Open the output as a `PrintWriter`, whose printing methods conveniently don't throw checked exceptions. You can call `checkError()` afterward to determine whether an exception occurred, but you can't get the actual exception.

Comment: @StuartMarks that’s a *horrible* design. Reminds me on `File.delete()` returning a `boolean`. But after two decades, `Files.delete(Path)` fixed it. So it seems that it is now understood that replacing an exception by a boolean was a bad idea. But why is there still no way to get the actual exception from `PrintWriter`, after a quarter century?

Comment: @Holger I agree this is a lousy design, but I've seen worse. :-) In general though the answer to "Why hasn't X been fixed after all this time?" is the same: scarcity of time and personnel, and priorities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this (update the code to close the resources):

```
    try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Path.of(outFile), StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
         Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Path.of(inFile))) {
        // Read the file using Files.lines and collect it into a List
        lines.map(line -> line.trim().replaceAll("aa", "bb"))
                .forEach(line -> {
                    try {
                        writer.write(line);
                        writer.newLine();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
                    }
                });
        writer.flush();
    }
```

Comment: Incredibly minor point, and may well be implied, but putting the `writer` in a try-with-resources block (or just wrapped in plain `try/catch` depending on the java version) would deal with ensuring it is closed in the case `UncheckedIOException` (or any other unchecked `Throwable`) occurs.

Comment: I tried it for an input file with around 3000 records, and faced the exception ```Exception in thread "main" java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1```. I do not face this exception if I reduce the number of records to mere 10. Also, the output file had all the records in a single line, instead of one record per line.

Comment: This is true, but the main idea was to show a possible solution to the problem than focusing on closing the resources.

Comment: I updated the code to add the a break after each line

Comment: @AbhinandanMadaan The code works without problems. I don't see any MalformedInputException. I tested with 1.000.000 lines (11Mb) and it took ~ 450ms to complete.

Comment: `forEach` should not be used here as it's waaay better to take an iterator from the stream and loop over it using the standard `while ( it.hasNext() ) { String line = it.next(); }` idiom that does not require any `UncheckedIOException` (guess which exception type will be caught on outer layers).

Comment: And a tiny performance bonus: that would allow save even on `map`.

Comment: @fluffy Either you use forEach either an iterator the result will be the same. The single difference is that on your case you will write more code.

Comment: @OctavianR. Sorry but no, there is no such a difference of "write more code" (especially for this case). There are differences: iterators do not require to use functions with shared state, iterators do not break lexical scope of the current function and do not require making variables "effectively final", and the client code won't need to catch for `UncheckedIOException`  -- how could it know that your code may throw it? I bet it can't.

Comment: @OctavianR. I tried with a different set of data, and it worked perfectly fine. I'm not sure what was the problem with my previous set of data. The input had 1260 characters per line The output file had around 400 lines less than the input file. Also thanks for the help. This was exactly what I was looking for. Cheers!

Comment: @fluffy Can you brielfly explain your approach? I'm intrigued.

Comment: @AbhinandanMadaan I mostly wrote it above: simply get an iterator from the stream: `Iterator<String> it = lines.iterator();`, loop over it and put `writer.write(line.trim().replace(...)); writer.newLine()` into the `while` loop. That's it: the code will be plain and straight-forward, and won't suffer of potential not-catching `UncheckedIOException` that is unchecked and not necessarily caught by the invoking code. BTW, `writer.flush()` is redundant: the `flush` will be done in `close` automatically.

Comment: @AbhinandanMadaan And even if going towards optimization: you don't even need to read the input source as lines as strings may consume much memory, and byte-oriented copying via a buffer replacing `aa` to `bb` would be even more fast. (However, I don't think your real problem is that simple...)

Comment: @fluffy the method Files.lines throws IOException but also UncheckedIOException, (please take a look on FileChannelLinesSpliterator). Also, why do you need to catch the IOException? What can you do with this exception, excepting closing the resources which is anyway done by the try with resources? The simple fact that Java has checked exceptions it is not a necessary a god think. In fact it was a bad decision took more than 20 years ago, decision which unfortunately caused a lot of problems for the evolution of this language. Don't believe me? Check the exception history in C#

Comment: @OctavianR. True, I missed the fact that the internal spliterator uses an unchecked variant of `IOException`, but we are not speculating on how good or bad checked exceptions are (I do believe they are good in very most cases). How I use checked exceptions: I control the flow in full; I know what can be thrown, and not what _might_ be thrown; I can be confident about mapping certain types of exceptions to another exceptions between application layers, and this all is featured by just language/compiler support.

Comment: @OctavianR. If you say that you can do nothing with checked exceptions, why wrapping them except of simply having them thrown through the `Consumer.accept` boundaries that do not declare `throws`? What can you do further if your code pretends on dealing with "oh, now it's not a checked exception, it's unchecked, let's do something with it'? It just can't do anything. Also, if you find `IOException` useless, why not append a catch to the try-with-resources statement, catch `IOException`s thrown from the try declaration block and wrap them all to `UncheckedIOException`? Would it be "less" code?

Comment: @fluffy let's close the discussion here and to not enter on the field of Java exceptions because this is a very opinionated subject (I'm coding also in other languages which either doesn't have exceptions either all of them are unchecked and it is wonderful). Btw, forEach is a stream terminal operation which should be used for side effect whatever is that one. "Terminal operations, such as Stream.forEach, may traverse the stream to produce a result or a side-effect" https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps

Comment: @OctavianR. I also write in many other languages, but sometimes having code not telling **formally** what it declares to do or throws freaks me out especially for legacy projects without documentation (especially for code like this that might throw either IOException or UncheckedIOException -- which to catch?). Also, I strongly disagree for _should be used_: no, it should not, I explained it multiple times above. Here are another three points for view despite I don't like it's point #2: https://blog.jooq.org/2015/12/08/3-reasons-why-you-shouldnt-replace-your-for-loops-by-stream-foreach/

Comment: @fluffy I see your point and in some cases it is perfect valid. I found myself in many situations when I need to know what type of exceptions a method throws in order to see what should I do (in most of the cases the exceptions regarding DB storage). But, for IOException, you don't care if it's IOException or UncheckedIOException. All you can do in this case is to close the opened resources (for any exceptions you have), stop the flow and bubble the exception in the upper layer to be logged or displayed to the end user. For your article, I strongly agree with the first point